# Where codeIgniter adds sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

**My query in model 'news_model'**

```
function get_tags($art_id) {

    $query = $this->db
            ->select('COUNT(tag2art.tag_id) AS quantity, tags.tag, tags.raw_tag')
            ->from('tag2art, tags')
            ->where('tag2art.tag_id = tags.tag_id')
            ->where('tag2art.art_id =', $art_id)
            ->group_by('tag2art.tag_id')
            ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $rows = $query->result();
        $query->free_result();
        return $rows;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**My controller where i used this model**

```
class News extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
        $this->load->model('articles_on_menu_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        if (empty($data)) {
            show_404();
        }
            foreach ($data['news'] as $key => $tags_news) {
                $data['news'][$key]['tags'] = $this->tagcloud($tags_news['news_id']);
            } 
        // this load other view
    }

    public function tagcloud($art_id) {
        $tags = $this->news_model->get_tags($art_id);
        if (!$tags) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $data['tags'][] = array($tag->quantity, $tag->tag, $tag->raw_tag);
        }
        return $data['tags'];
    }
}
```

Then I turn on the site.com/news and get the sql error

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'
>
> SELECT COUNT(tag2art.tag_id) AS quantity, `tags`.`tag`,
>   `tags`.`raw_tag` FROM (`tag2art`, `tags`) WHERE `tag2art`.`tag_id` =
>   tags.tag_id AND `tag2art`.`art_id` = '65' GROUP BY `tag2art`.`tag_id`
>   ORDER BY `id` desc
>
> Filename: Z:\home\blogj.ru\www\system\database\DB_driver.php

Whence came this request

> ORDER BY `id` desc

Comment: You need to add the table name to the ID column: `$this->db->order_by('tablename.id', 'DESC');`

Comment: tables are not present in my columns with id

Comment: @MihailKuznetsov Are you inheriting any custom model in your code?

Comment: This is caused in your model class. You didn't give complete model class, I guess you have a `$_order_by = 'id';` variable. May be due inheriting.

Comment: @kumar_v Thank you!!! My mistake was that I used in the model News_model another function which was specified $ this-> db-> order_by ("news.id", "desc"); Now I'll know that the design of $ this-> db-> order_by ("news.id", "desc"); applies to all functions within the current model

Comment: @kumar_v how can I close this issue?

Comment: Others will close. You don't have much reputation to close.